# Unexpected request: POST /api/v1/auth/sign_in Expected POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test case for sign in factory (in jasmine, and running it with karma), but its throwing 'Unexpected request: POST /api/v1/auth/sign_in Expected POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in' error every time I try to run the test.

My factory code is as follows:

```
app.factory('signUpFactory', function($http, baseUrl, access_token){
  // authUrl = baseUrl + "/auth";
  authUrl = "/api/v1/auth";
  var signup_user = {};
  var headers = { 'Authorization': 'Token token="' + access_token + '"' };
//Sign in
  signup_user.signIn = function(formData){
    var dataObj = {
      login_id: formData.email,
      password:formData.password,
      login_type: formData.login_type
    };
    return $http.post(authUrl+"/sign_in" , dataObj, {headers: headers});
  };

  return signup_user;
});
```

and the corresponding test case for the same is:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('Registrations Factory: signUpFactory', function(){
    var signUpFactory;
    var $httpBackend,
        response;

    var loginForm = {};

    beforeEach(module('abc'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_signUpFactory_, _$httpBackend_){
      signUpFactory = _signUpFactory_;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    }));

    it('should sign in if valid params are present', function(){
      var dataObj = {
        login_id: 'email@abc.com',
        password: '123456789',
        login_type: 'Doctor'
      };

      loginForm.email = 'email@abc.com';
      loginForm.password = '123456789';
      loginForm.login_type = 'Doctor';

      $httpBackend.expect('POST','http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in', dataObj).respond("success");

      signUpFactory.signIn(loginForm)
      .then(function(data){
        response = data.status;
      })

      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(response).toEqual("success");
    })
  })
})();
```

I searched for possible solutions, but could not fix it. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Well, the URL that the code actually posts to is `/api/v1/auth/sign_in`, and the test expects the URL to be `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in`. So they're different.

Comment: Even if i replace url in the service with "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in", then I get another error which says "Unexpected request: GET partials/shared/home.html
 No more request expected"

Comment: That's unrelated to that test.

Comment: ok, I think the issue is due to 'ngHtml2JsPreprocessor' that I have used for resolving the dependency 'templates', since I am using angular-rails-template to create asset pipeline

Comment: A test that tests a service should not try loading a template. You're probably loading the whole main module that configures the router and starts the application, instead of just loading the sub-module containing that service.

Comment: yes, module 'abc' is the main module of the project, could you please suggest me how I will be able to load a sub-module that contains the service.

Comment: Make sure you have several modules, splitted by feature or by technical layer. The main module should be almost empty and contain only the run and config blocks of the whole app. Load only the module containing the service in your test, i.e. replace `module('abc')` by `module('registration')` or `module('services')`.

Comment: Actually we are having only one main module, that contains all the controllers, factories, partials, services and directives, and in beforeEach function I am instantiating that module so that I can create instant for service/ factory that I need to test, I am not able to figure out how should I proceed, as I am new to TDD

Comment: That's the problem. You should have several smaller modules, and only load the module(s) you need in every test. Just as I described in my previous comment.

Comment: I have following files in karma.conf.js file,
files:['app/assets/javascripts/ng-app/app.js.erb','app/assets/javascripts/ng-app/run.js.erb','app/assets/javascripts/ng-app/**/**/*.js','spec/javascripts/**/*.js','app/assets/templates/partials/**/*.html','app/assets/templates/partials/*.html','app/assets/templates/directives/*.html'],
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {'templates' moduleName: 'templates'},
preprocessors: {'app/assets/templates/partials/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],'app/assets/templates/partials/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],'app/assets/templates/directives/*.html': ['ng-html2js']}

Comment: ok, I thought I have problem in karma configuration file. Thank you, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using use regex:

```
 $httpBackend.expect('POST',/.*\/api\/v1\/auth\/sign_in/, dataObj).respond("success");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/e1udbtst/

Comment: Cool, that worked, but now I am getting an error like 'Unexpected request: GET partials/shared/home.html
 No more request expected'

Comment: you're probably expecting another request... 
i'de use $httpBackend.when(...)

Comment: well I have not written test case for any other service.

Comment: solved the issue with 'beforeEach(module('uiRouterNoop'))';